# Aligning four squares two by two

Tags: html, css, web

i want four divs inside a wrapper div that would be optimized for all resolutions.
Here is an example of what i want:

[image]

This may be a very newbie question but i couldn't get this fixed and to work on all resolutions,thanks for taking your time into reading my question.

Comment: What did you try, how far did you get and where are you stuck?

Comment: You imply you do have it working for _some_ resolutions, so let's start from there.

Comment: What do you mean by *optimizing for all resolutions*? These are just four rectangles. There is nothing to optimize without any content.

Comment: Check out ```display: table```

Answer (score 0):

You can just float two divs next to each other with a width of 50%. I have also changed the box-sizing to include the border so I can put in borders to show you where the boxes are.

You can see the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/njy8925n/

```
width:50%;
float:left;
box-sizing:border-box;
```

Edit: if you want their heights to be equal to their widths, then it will be a bit trickier...